# Bootstrap tab panel event

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un tab panel de bootstrap con 5 pestañas intercambiables (in active, fade, fade, fade, fade)

Dentro de cada una de estas pestañas está incluida una dxchart (devextreme) que se grafica con Jscript.

Cuando mi página termina de cargar , la gráfica que se encuentra en el tab con la clase css: (in active) aparece apropiadamente. Pero si navego en los otros tabs las gráficas no se crean.

He investigado sobre el caso y he descubierto que las gráficas en los tabs (fade) tienen que ser creadas en el evento tabchanged.

No soy muy bueno en Jscript, y me la paso investigado cada detalle de código. He encotrado y modificado lo siguiente:

```
var isShown = false;

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
//  e.target // newly activated tab
//    e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
DrawChart(); isShown = true;           
})


function DrawChart() {
if (isShown)
    return;

$("#chartUtilidad").dxChart({
    dataSource: chartDataBar,
    commonSeriesSettings: {
        bar: {
            cornerRadius: 10
        },
        argumentField: 'ano_a'
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        format: "fixedPoint",
        precision: 2,
    },

    series: [
        { valueField: 'ing1_f', name: 'Ingreso', type: 'bar', color: '#4F81BC' },
        { valueField: 'cost1_f', name: 'Costo', type: 'bar', color: '#9BBB58' },
        { valueField: 'gastos1', name: 'Gasto', type: 'bar', color: '#23BFAA' },
        { valueField: 'uti1', name: 'Utilidad', type: 'bar', color: '#8064A1' },
    ],
    argumentAxis: {
        //tickInterval: { years: 1 },
        argumentType: 'string'
    },
    legend: {
        horizontalAlignment: 'center',
        font: { color: 'Black', size: 20 },
    },


    title: {
        text: 'Comparativo C$'
    },
    animation: {
        easing: 'easeOutCubic',
        duration: 3000
    }

});

}
```

Normalmente el código para crear las gráficas es el siguiente (me funciona bien en el "in active"):

```
$(function () {



$("#chartVentas").dxChart({
    dataSource: chartData,

    commonSeriesSettings: {
        type: "line",
        hoverMode: "allArgumentPoints",
        selectionMode: "allArgumentPoints",
        label: {
            visible: false,
        },
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        format: "fixedPoint",
        precision: 2,
        //customizeText: function () {
        //    return this.valueText + ' C$';
        //}
    },
    series: [
    { argumentField: 'argumento1', valueField: 'vtas1', name: '2016', color: '#4f81bc' },
    { argumentField: 'argumento2', valueField: 'vtas2', name: '2015', color: '#bc8a4f' },
    ],
    argumentAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
    },
    legend: {
        horizontalAlignment: 'center',
        font: { color: 'Black', size: 20 },
    },

    title: 'Cajas vendidas C$',

    animation: {
        easing: 'easeOutCubic',
        duration: 3000
    }


});

});
```

No sé como tiene que estar estructurado el código para el tabchanged event.

Este es el HTML:

```
<div class="container">  
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#venta">Ventas</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#costo">Costos</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#comparativo">Comparativo</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#caja">Cajas</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="venta" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div id="chartVentas"></div>
</div>
<div id="costo" class="tab-pane fade">

</div>
<div id="comparativo" class="tab-pane fade">

  <div id="chartUtilidad"></div>

 </div>
<div id="caja" class="tab-pane fade">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Ventas (in active)]
[image: Chart utilidades (fade)]

Comment: Noel, si el problema es que no se cargan los mapas en los tabs no activos, haz que se carguen al cambiar el foco añadiendo un evento

Comment: Si, correcto es lo que intento hacer pero no soy muy bueno en JS, algun ejemplo a seguir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noel, si el problema es que no se cargan los mapas en los tabs no activos, haz que se carguen al cambiar el foco añadiendo un evento

> Si, correcto es lo que intento hacer pero no soy muy bueno en JS, algun ejemplo a seguir?

Lo que necesitas es añadir eventos a las pestañas. Tienes muchas maneras de hacerlo, via html directamente usando el atributo `onclick`, por ejemplo.

Yo, por costumbre, en estos casos declaro los listeners via js/jquery.

---

Si dispones de `javascript`/`HTML` (`DOM`) puro mira [este ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/L0zuwue8/1/):

```
var ventas = document.getElementById('ventas');
ventas.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert( "Carga grafico de ventas" );
}, false);
```

---

Si tienes `JQuery` mira [este otro ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/jyfvztc2/):

```
$( "#costos" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Carga grafico de compras" );
});
```

---

Si en cambio tienes JQuery UI puedes cojer [el evento `tabs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928314/jquery-onchange-in-tabs-event) (link en ingles)

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("PRESSED TAB!");
    }
});
```

Comment: El Jquery me ha funcionado (el de en medio de tu publicación), pero no de la manera que deseo, una vez que selecciono otra pestaña la gráfica no me carga, tengo que hacer un 2do click en la misma pestaña ya seleccionada para que la gráfica se muestre con todas las de la ley lo cual me satisface al final, no se que evento estaremos redactando incorrectamente.

Answer (score 1):

A ver, aqui hace falta conocer el backend que andas utilizando. Encontré esta posible solución:

Primero (ASPX):

```
<dx:ASPxPageControl ID="ASPxPageControl1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"> Algo de contenido<ClientSideEvents Init="function (s,e) {  DrawChart(); }" /> </dx:ASPxPageControl>
```

Segundo (ASPX):

```
<dx:ASPxPageControl ID="ASPxPageControl1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"><ClientSideEvents ActiveTabChanged="function (s,e) { DrawChart(); isShown = true;}" /></dx:ASPxPageControl>
```

Tercero (JavaScript):

```
var isShown = false;
function DrawChart() {
if (isShown)
    return;

$("#chartContainer"}).dxChart({
    // add chart options
   })
}
```

Enlace de referencia: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18850

Con respecto a lo que dices sobre `tabchanged`, me parece que te hace falta agregar un evento onclick en cada tab llamando a la función: "function (s,e) { DrawChart(); isShown = true;}".

A modo de recomendacion: utiliza D3.js o Google Charts para ese tipo de gráficas, ambas librerías son OpenSource, gratuitas, con excelente documentación y buena comunidad de soporte. Con respecto a DevExpress... Entre más lo conozco, más lejos quiero estar de ese framework, en lo personal me ha dado dolores de cabeza en especial cuando todos quieren actualizar... Mira la cantidad de líneas de código que genera y el compilador que tienes en el C:\erebro explotará de un Overflow (ok no!).

Bueno, espero te haya sido de utilidad, sigue adelante con todo el power!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo no estoy utilizando eventos ASP para los tab pane, al contrario necesito eventos en los tab pane de bootstrap.

Comment: de nada, por lo que me dices, siento que solo estas utilizando HTML5, JavaScript y CSS3, estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: intenta con esto: <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#venta" onclick="function (s,e) { DrawChart(); isShown = true;}">Ventas</a></li>